# only count rows that don't have a repeating value MYSQL

Tags: mysql

I want to count the number of rows in a table, excluding rows that have 2 or more fields with the value: 0.

eg:

**do** count this:

```
            col1  col2 col3
            -----|-----|-----   <- only 1 zero: OK
              0  |  1  |  2
```

**don't** count this:

```
             col1  col2 col3
            -----|-----|-----   <- more than 1 zero: don't count this row
              0  |  0  |  2
```

is there a MYSQL command for this?
Thank you

Comment: How many columns are you counting? It's just a few case or if expressions.

Comment: @Salman A: the table has 6 columns

Comment: The table sounds like a violation of 3NF.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a case statement to count the number of rows that have that condition:

```
SELECT SUM(
    CASE
        WHEN
            (col1 = 0) +
            (col2 = 0) +
            (col3 = 0) +
            (col4 = 0) +
            (col5 = 0) +
            (col6 = 0) < 2
        THEN 1
        ELSE 0
    END
) AS count
FROM table;
```